# Selection in PrimeNG Dropdown Using Id

Tags: primeng

My application has the UI getting its data through Rest calls. The objects in my list for the dropdown have this type of structure

```
{
    id: "xxxx-yyyy-dddd",
    name: "Porfolio Name",
    more_fields: "Blah Blah Blah"
}
```

The problem is that my "selected_portfolio" value that I receive from the server, is just the "id" of the item that needs to be selected. Is there a way to have the selection work without having to search through the list to get an actual instance of the portfolio.

This is what I have right now for my dropdown in the HTML. I was hoping that the "id" field in the dataKey would match the "selected_portfolio", which is the "id' of one of the instances in my "portfolios" list.

```
<p-dropdown dataKey="id" [options]="portfolios" optionLabel="name" [(ngModel)]="selected_portfolio" (onChange)="updateSelectedPortfolio($event)"></p-dropdown>
```